# Getting the computed width of an element after modification

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, prototypejs

I have a routine that sizes elements in a page to fit snugly within their parent. In most cases, it is working admirably, but in Firefox (JUST Firefox - Chrome, IE, etc are fine) it is fumbling on the first attempt in one particular instance - a div nested within a fieldset fails to resize on the first attempt, but succeeds on the second (and subsequent) attempts.

Each element is sized relative to its parent using the following:

```
function resizeChild(elem) {
    // Get gutter based on margins, borders, padding, etc
    var gutter = getGutter(elem); // returns obj with x and y properties
    var parent = elem.parentElement;
    var parentStyles = window.computedStyle(parent);
    var targetWidth = (parseInt(parentStyles['width']) - gutter.x;
    var widthPx = targetWidth + 'px';
    // prototype.js setStyle shortcut
    elem.setStyle({
        width: widthPx,
        maxWidth: widthPx,
        minWidth: widthPx
    });
}
```

I run this in a loop, iterating over every element with a particular CSS class.

According to the Firefox debugger, the outer element (the fieldset) is always being resized before the inner div. I can inspect the element, and see the style attributes being set appropriately. However, on the next iteration of the loop, when the parent is being evaluated (I can see in the javascript property inspector that the parent is indeed the fieldset), the value for width that is returned for the computed style is the previous, unmodified value, thus the inner div is resized incorrectly.

Can somebody shed some light on this please?

**Edits after comments:**

`parent.clientWidth` returns 0.

Not sure if this is relevant, but a parent div of the fieldset had `display` set to `none` shortly prior the resize operation being called. However, at the point at which the fieldset was resized, the `display` of the div was set to `inline-block`. I don't **think** this would make a difference, but then I'm not well educated on some of the particular behaviours of Firefox in this scenario.

Comment: Did you see this page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: I have :) The problem, in this case, is that many of the standard API methods for querying the layout of the parent div return 0 the first time this particular region of the page is sized - the only non-zero values I get are from the computed style. Unfortunately, the computed style seems to contain the dimensions of the parent element from **before** it was resized, if it was also resized.

Comment: It is almost as if - just putting this out there, as an idle musing - as if Firefox were treating the resizeFullWidth() function as a transactional unit, and not applying the altered properties to the DOM unti lthe entire function has completed.

Comment: Can you update javascript with simple HTML test page so it can be copied and quickly tested?

Comment: I think it would be tricky to replicate in static HTML, due to the number of moving parts. (edit - curse this editor not allowing linebreaks :P). Prior to this, the content is being loaded into a parent region using an Ajax.Updater object from prototype.js. The parent div itself is dynamically generated as part of a tabbed window. Simpler examples exist on my site and are functioning - it's just this fringe case that's giving me trouble.

Comment: That is unfortunate - I have no time to create test file...

Comment: Fair enough, man - I'm in the same boat myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this, although it's a little situational.

It seems that if the width of the parent element has been dynamically modified using `prototype.js#Element.setStyle()` (and, for all I know, other libraries that directly modify the `style` attribute), then the `computedStyle()` method won't reflect the change until all changes have completed.

The solution was to check to see if the parent element of the element being resized also had the CSS class that flagged the elements for resize, and if it did, get the size from the `style` attribute instead of using `computedStyle()`. Here's the full function, with modifications:

```
function resizeFullwidth() {
    $$('*.fullWidth').each(function(elem, i) {
        // Get gutter based on margins, borders, padding, etc
        var gutter = getGutter(elem); // returns obj with x and y properties
        var parent = elem.parentElement;
        var parentStyles = (
            parent.hasClassName('fullWidth')
                ? window.computedStyle(parent)
                : parent.style);
        var targetWidth = (parseInt(parentStyles['width']) - gutter.x;
        var widthPx = targetWidth + 'px';
        // prototype.js setStyle shortcut
        elem.setStyle({
            width: widthPx,
            maxWidth: widthPx,
            minWidth: widthPx
        });
    });
}
```

This now works correctly in all browsers :)

Thanks very much for your help, people :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `var targetWidth = parent.clientWidth` ?

See : [MDN Element.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

Comment: I have. At the point at which this executes, parent.clientWidth returns 0.

Not sure if this is relevant, but a parent div of the fieldset had `display` set to `none` shortly prior the resize operation being called. However, at the point at which the fieldset was resized, the `display` of the div was set to `inline-block`. I don't **think** this would make a difference, but then I'm not well educated on some of the particular behaviours of Firefox in this scenario.

Comment: @Minouris.  You can't return the width of an element with `display:none` so perhaps it's because the code is executing faster than Firefox can update the DOM?